# Read Data from Excel Sheet in C#, .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Excel Data reader read data from Excel sheet in order compare it with the UI dropdown values and see if they exists

I am trying to read data from excel sheet using below code

// methods to read data and parse the data into populate collection

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace GorillaUITests.PageObjects
{
    public class ExcelRead
    {
        public static List<Datacollection> dataCol = new List<Datacollection>();

        public static DataTable ExcelToDataTable(string fileName)
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    var result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()

                    {
                        UseColumnDataType = true,

                        ConfigureDataTable = (data) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseHeaderRow = true
                        }
                    });

                    //Get all the Tables
                    DataTableCollection table = result.Tables;
                    //Store it in DataTable
                    DataTable resultTable = table["Sheet1"];
                    //return
                    return resultTable;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void PopulateInCollection(string fileName)
        {
            DataTable table = ExcelToDataTable(fileName);

            //Iterate through the rows and columns of the Table
            for (int row = 1; row <= table.Rows.Count; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
                {
                    Datacollection dtTable = new Datacollection()
                    {
                        rowNumber = row,
                        colName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName,
                        colValue = table.Rows[row - 1][col].ToString()
                    };
                    //Add all the details for each row
                    dataCol.Add(dtTable);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Read data from Collection
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="rowNumber"></param>
        /// <param name="columnName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ReadData(int rowNumber, string columnName)
        {
            try
            {
                //Retriving Data using LINQ to reduce much of iterations
                string data = (from colData in dataCol
                               where colData.colName == columnName && colData.rowNumber == rowNumber
                               select colData.colValue).SingleOrDefault();

                //var datas = dataCol.Where(x => x.colName == columnName && x.rowNumber == rowNumber).SingleOrDefault().colValue;
                return data.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }


    }

    public class Datacollection
    {
        public int rowNumber { get; set; }
        public string colName { get; set; }

        public string colValue { get; set; }
    }
}

// Test to see if we are able to read data

public void ReadDataFromExcel(string user, string pass)
        {
            // populate data in collection

            try
            {
                ExcelRead.PopulateInCollection(@"C:\Users\username\Documents\GorillaUITests\GorillaUITests\Tests\Data\ReadDataTest.xlsx");

                Debug.WriteLine("UserName:" + ExcelRead.ReadData(1, "UserName"));
                Debug.WriteLine("Email:" + ExcelRead.ReadData(1, "Email"));
                Debug.WriteLine("***********");
                Debug.WriteLine("UserName:" + ExcelRead.ReadData(2, "UserName"));
                Debug.WriteLine("Email:" + ExcelRead.ReadData(2, "Email"));
                Debug.WriteLine("***********");
                Debug.WriteLine("Username:" + ExcelRead.ReadData(2, "UserName"));
                Debug.WriteLine("Email:" + ExcelRead.ReadData(2, "Email"));
                Debug.WriteLine("***********");
                           
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

And I see this error below

“Object reference not set to an instance of an object.”

Not sure what I am missing, Any inputs would be appreciated

Comment: When you get that error, it tells you exactly which line caused it. You failed to include that information in your post.

Comment: You have a null object. Somewhere, somehow, you are trying to read or execute behaviour from, and instance of an object that is null. 

The precise line, this exception happens on, is included when you debug your code. Simply verify the location, and initialize this object correctly, or remove nullable properties.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)